# Parquet schema and Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, parquet, spark-csv

I am trying to convert CSV files to parquet and i am using Spark to accomplish this.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName(appName)
    .config("spark.master", master)
    .getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> logFile = spark.read().csv("log_file.csv");
logFile.write().parquet("log_file.parquet");
```

Now the problem is i don't have a schema defined and columns look like this (output displayed using printSchema() in spark)

```
root
 |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
 ....
```

the csv has the names on the first row but they're ignored i guess, the problem is only a few columns are strings, i also have ints and dates.

I am **only** using Spark, no avro or anything else basically (never used avro).

What are my options to define a schema and how? If i need to write the parquet file in another way then no problem as long as it's a quick an easy solution.

(i am using spark standalone for tests / don't know scala)

Comment: have you tried the `.option("inferschema",true)` while reading the csv ?

Comment: @rajat just tried, it's better but not perfect, saw somewhere that i could use `StructType` for this. (also used `option("header", true)`) I have another problem however, some columns are null and they shouldn't be ... let me check the CSV, not sure how spark expects the format exactly (quotes or no quotes)

Comment: while reading through spark-csv you can specify the `option("mode","FAILFAST")` this will give error if the any row doesn't have the same schema as specified.

Comment: you can explore other options https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: I was actually checking that page and was experimenting, found it after you told me about `inferschema`. Unfortunately my data has some problems because of some unicode issues so i need to postptone this and get back back to building the CSVs. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: basically yes, it proposed a schema and it used the csv header for column names

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the .option("inferschema","true") present [Spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) package. This will automatically infer the schema from the data.

You can also define a custom schema for your data using struct type and use the `.schema(schema_name)` to read the on the basis of a custom schema.

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("year", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("make", StringType, true),
    StructField("model", StringType, true),
    StructField("comment", StringType, true),
    StructField("blank", StringType, true)))

val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
    .schema(customSchema)
    .load("cars.csv")
```